# Get ObservableInput value and avoid subscription to it

Tags: angular, rxjs

I got an ObservableInput in my Angular component, and also a Subject button that on press, I get the input value, and call another observable, then subscribe to it to use the returned data.

But the problem is that whenever this input changes, it triggers the (onClick) function that isn't meant to be triggered without clicking as it's subscribed to the input automatically because I'm using switchMap.

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
class SomeComponent {
   @ObservableInput @Input() name$: Observable<string>;
   private clickSubject = new Subject<Event>();

   constructor(private _someService: Service) {
      this.clickSubject.pipe(
          switchMap(() => this.name$),
          switchMap((name) => this._someService.getUserByName(name))
      ).subscribe((data: UserData) => {
          // Work around with data here.
      });
   }

   onUserClick(): void {
       clickSubject.next();
   }
}
```

I read that I could use "merge()" from RxJS, but I can't seem to find a way to make it work. `mergeMap` also returns an Observable but subscribes to name$ which is not desired.

I need to only get current name$ value without subscribing to it so whenever it changes, it doesn't trigger whatever is on subscribe block.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need here to make the `name$` an `@ObservableInput`. If it's only use is to be used an a parameter to the HTTP request, it could just be a plain Angular `@Input` property. It could then be accessed inside the `switchMap` using `this.name`.

```js
class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
   Input() name: string;
   private clickSubject = new Subject<Event>();

   ngOnInit(private _someService: Service) {
     this.clickSubject.pipe(
       switchMap(() => this._someService.getUserByName(this.name))
     ).subscribe((data: UserData) => {
       // Work around with data here.
     });
   }

   onUserClick(): void {
     clickSubject.next();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thing is that i need this property to be an observable as it dynamically changes and listens to this change when component isn't destroyed. Would be kind of the same as using ngOnChange. As the only suscription that i have is on the click, for some reason even though the normal Input changed its value, it wouldn't be assigned to `this.name`.

Comment: I don't get it. So are you saying the variable `this.name` in the child contains the old value even though a new value has been set in the parent using the `[name]="someVar"` binding?

Comment: Yes, even though i'm passing it as `[name]="someVar"`, it won't update within the component. I've read that it's suggested to have a subscription on the input. Some use a BehaviorSubject on input.